# Which programming language is `cron` file made of?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I stumbled upon a CRON file and read that cron files can be written in essentially any language, so I am having issues identifying the language of this CRON job.

The only line in the file is:

```
0 7 * * 1 program/bin/env -e ${ENVIRONMENT_ALIAS} ${ENVIRONMENT_ROOT}/bin/pop.py
```

I thought this was a bash script but the numbers at the beginning confuse me. Does anyone know what language this is?

Comment: `man 5 crontab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each entry in a crontab file consists of six fields, specifying in the following order:

`minute(s) hour(s) day(s) month(s) weekday(s) command(s)`

So in your case your job will run on 7AM on weekday 1 which is monday

See https://kb.iu.edu/d/afiz for more details

Edit : As mentioned by tripleee you can use https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info as well.

Comment: Or simply the [Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](/tags/cron/info)

Comment: Oh interesting. So if I were to add an if statement so that it would only run under certain conditions, what language would my if statement be in? Bash?

Comment: Shell script yes, but specifically Bash no. The script will be run by legacy `sh` so you cannot use Bash extensions.

Answer (score 2):

cron file is a configuration file that set the crontab, it is not programming language as it. The crontab job stuff is the software.

[CRON](https://github.com/Cron/Cron)